# Partial Differential Equations - Using separation of variables to solve this modified heat equation

Tags: calculus, differential

Here's the modified heat equation i was given : $\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{\mathrm{d}^2u}{\mathrm{d}x^2} + u$ , $L = \pi$, $BC = 0$ at both ends ( $x = 0$ and $\pi$ )

IC: $u (x,0) = x(\pi - x)$

Here's my attempt at constructing ODEs for $F(x)$ and $G(t)$

let $u(x,t) = F(x)G(t)$

$\implies G^{\prime}(t)F(x) = F^{\prime \prime}(x)G(t) + F(x)G(t)$

$\cfrac{G^{\prime}(t)}{G(t)} = \cfrac{F^{\prime \prime}(x)+F(x)}{F(x)} = a$, where $a$ is the separation constant

solving for $F(X)$:

$F^{\prime \prime}(x) - F(x)a + F(x) = 0$

$F^{\prime \prime}(x) + F(x)(1-a) = 0$

This is where i get stuck, is it safe to assume that since a is some constant, then $(1 - a)$ is also some arbitrary constant as well? , say $p^2$

If so, then the rest of steps in solving for F(x) seems to be simple enough

For, $p^2 \gt 0$

Which should eventually just give me $F(x) = \sin(nx)$, where $n = R/0$

If so, how does this affect me trying to find the general solution for $G(t)$?

Trying to solve for $G(t)$:

$\cfrac{G^{\prime}(t)}{G(t)} = a$

$G^{\prime}(t) - (a)G(t) = 0$

Comment: Welcome to Maths SE.  __2__ things: I have reformatted some of your equations this time but the input interpretation may be wrong so in future use [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?lq=1) to learn how to format via $LaTeX$ and secondly, if someone gives an answer that is useful to you don't forget to tick it. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $K=-\partial _{x}^{2}$ has real, non-negative, discrete spectrum,
\begin{equation*}
K=\sum_{n}\lambda _{n}|v_{n}><v_{n}|
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
u(t)=\exp [Kt]u(0)=\sum_{n}e^{\lambda _{n}t}<v_{n}|u(0)>v_{n}(x)
\end{equation*}
so you see that your ansatz only works if $<v_{n}|u(0)>$ vanishes for all
but one $n$.